# no aparecen mis imagenes de mi interfaz de java

Tags: java, imagen, vscode, cmd, interfaz-gráfica

estoy hacionedo una aplicacion en java y estoy utilazando vscode en mi interfaz utilizo 3 imagenes pero al momento de correrlo las imagenes no aparecen pero si cargo el mismo archivo con el simbolo de sistema las imagenes aparencen y el mismo error me sucede si lo hago en netbeans
como puedo hacer que las imagenes cargen en vscode

esto es lo que me sale en vscode[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

y esto es lo que me sale con cmd[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

alguien sabe como puedo solucionarlo
para que salga las imagenes

Comment: Quizas vscode ejecuta la aplicacion desde un directorio base diferente. Como pones la referencia a las imagenes? Direcciones relativas o absolutas? Tu codigo deberia incluir logs en caso que el archivo a cargar no se encuentre.

Comment: Hola! Bienvenidx a SOes. 
Las preguntas del tipo "Tengo que hacer esto" sin mostrar el código que has escrito no suelen ser bien recibidas, ya que la respuesta será siempre adivinando y no encaja en el formato del sitio.
Recomiendo que hagas el [recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) para entender el sitio y de paso ganar tu primera medalla. 
También estaría bien que revisaras [Cómo preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) para que recibas respuesta cuanto antes.

Comment: Recuerda que puedes [edit] tu pregunta cuantas veces sea necesario (incluso si termina cerrada) y añadir la info relevante a forma de [Ejemplo mínimo](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) (en los comentarios no se ve bien el código y abajo sólo van nuestros intentos de respuesta).

Comment: ¿Responde esto a tu pregunta? [Error al cargar imagenes en Netbeans](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/387880/error-al-cargar-imagenes-en-netbeans)